API Google Search Console получить доступ от владельца аккаунта
У меня есть аккаунт в GSC.
В аккаунте несколько сайтов.
Как могу получить доступ от себя к аналитике всех сайтов в GSC не создавая отдельных API key или Client ID или сервисного аккаунта для каждого сайта?
